# until/while and the chain $?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, scripting

I want to execute a command in a loop until it exits with the exit code `0`, so I tried:

```bsh
$ while/until $?; do $command; done
```

But `until/while` seems to only accept booleans like `true/false` and not `0/1`.

Did I miss something like `[[ ]]` or something else?

Answer (score 15):

The `while` and `until` keywords takes a *command* as their argument.  If the command returns a zero exit-status, signalling "success", `while` would run the commands in the body of the loop, while `until` would *not* run the commands in the body of the loop.

Your code seems to use `while` and `until` with `$?`, the exit-status of the most recent command, as a command.  This will not work, unless you have commands with integers as names on the system.  What *would* work is to use the `test` command to compare it against `0`, for example, with

```bsh
until test "$?" -eq 0; do some-command; done
```

or, using the short form of `test`,

```
until [ "$?" -eq 0 ]; do some-command; done
```

The issue now is obviously that `$?` may well be zero when entering the loop, preventing the loop from running even once.  It would make more sense to let the command itself give its exit-status directly to either `while` or `until` (unless you want to initialize `$?` to a non-zero value by calling e.g. `false` just before the loop, which would look strange).

Using standard POSIX (though not Bourne, not that it matters much these days) shell syntax:

```bsh
while ! some-command; do continue; done
```

or (both Bourne and POSIX),

```bsh
until some-command; do continue; done
```

Both of these runs `some-command` until it returns a zero exit-status ("success").  In each iteration, it executes the `continue` keyword inside the loop body.  Executing `continue` skips ahead to the next iteration of the loop immediately, but you could replace it with e.g. `sleep 5` to have a short delay in each iteration, or with `:` which does nothing.

Another variant would be to have an *infinite* loop that you exit when your command succeeds:

```bsh
while true; do some-command && break; done
```

or, slightly more verbose, and with added air for readability,

```bsh
while true; do
    if some-command; then
        break
    fi
done
```

---

The only time you actually *need* to use `$?` is when you are required to keep track of this value for a while, as in

```
somefunction () {
    grep -q 'pattern' file
    ret=$?
    
    if [ "$ret" -ne 0 ]; then
        printf 'grep failed with exit code %s\n' "$ret"
    fi >&2
    
    return "$ret"
}
```

In the code above, the exit-status in `$?` is reset by the test `[ "$ret" -ne 0 ]` and we would not be able to print its value nor return it from the function without storing it in a separate variable.

---

Another thing to point out is that you seem to be using a *string*, `$command` (unquoted), as your command.  It would be *much better* to use an array if you want to run a command stored in a variable:

```bsh
thecommand=( awk -F ',' 'BEGIN { "uptime" | getline; split($4,a,": "); if (a[2] > 5) exit 1 }' )

while ! "${thecommand[@]}"; do sleep 5; done
```

(This example code sleeps in intervals of five seconds until the 1-minute average system load has gone below 5.)

Note how by using an array and quoting the expansion as `"${thecommand[@]}"`, I can run my command without worrying about how the shell would split the string into words and apply filename globbing to each of those words.

See also [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444946) for more info on this aspect of your issue.

Comment: Instead of `test` or `[` I'd recommend using arithmetic expansion: `while (($?))` …

Comment: @KonradRudolph Can you motivate why you would want to do that? Take into account that the rest of my answer is free of bash-ism and that I _don't_ actually recommend using `test` or `[` but to let the `while` or `until` keywords act on the exist-status of the command _directly_ (by executing the command) instead of on `$?`.

Comment: The question is tagged Bash. I’m fine with avoiding *most* bashisms to improve portability, but using `[`/`test` is simply *a lot more error-prone* than the Bash alternatives. That said, the real solution (which your answer contains) of course uses none of these alternatives.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I think we have a matter of opinion and/or personal preference here. I tend to keep to POSIX syntax if I can, as making a script, or portion of a script, non-portable on _purpose_ seems unnecessary.  Also, developers that have issues with quoting for `test`, will also have issues with the special syntactic sugar that `bash` provides.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
false; while [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; do
  command
done
```

Here, `false` would initially set `$?` to a non-zero value, allowing the loop to run at least once. The loop then runs the given command until it exits with a zero exit-status.